# Hibernate3 many to many cascade deleting with cleanup

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many, cascade, hibernate-cascade

I have a problem with cascade deleting in Hibernate 3.6. I have the following many to many relationship between two entity classes: Menu and Item. Note that this is a uni-directional relationship. A Menu instance has a reference the set of Items it has. But an Item instances do not know about Menu instances it belongs to.

```
@Entity
public class Menu {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(
        name = "Menu_Item",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "menu_id")}
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "item_id")},
    )
    private Set<Item> items = new HashSet<Item>();

    ....
}


@Entity
public class Item { 
    @Id  
    private Long id; 

    private String name;

    private String code;

    ...
}
```

**My requirement:** An row in the `Item` table should exist in the database only if at least one `Menu` entry refers to it. That is, an item that does not belong to any menu should not exist in the database.

Now, assume the following scenario,

menu1 has [item1, item2]

menu2 has [item1]

When I invoke `session.remove(menu1)`, Hibernate tries to remove both `item1` and `item2` from the `Item` table (this operation is actually rejected by the dataset). I want Hibernate to remove only `item2`, since there is another menu using `item1`.

I'm aware that I can prevent associated Items being deleted when a Menu is deleted by making `cascade` not include `CascadeType.DELETE`. But I don't want this behavior either: I do want `item2` to be deleted from the database (since no menu is using it, i.e., it has no associations in the Menu_Item table).

What is the best to achieve this in Hibernate?